# Minimization model with initial starting values

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm trying to solve a minimization problem where an initial solution is already present and the objective function is based on this initial solution.

I have some sort of line `y_line` which is an initial mapping of resources and stations:

```
y_line = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1]])
```

Additionally, I have a savings array for selling from the line `S`, an array for buying new `EC` and for processing `P`

```
S = np.array([[-260., -260., -260.],
              [-30.,  -30.,  -30.],
              [360.,  360.,  360.]], dtype=int)
EC = np.array([[1000, 1000, 1000],
               [2000, 2000, 2000],
               [5000, 5000, 5000]], dtype=int)
P = np.array([[720.,  720.,  720.],
              [1440., 1440., 1440.],
              [3600., 3600., 3600.]], dtype=int)
```

Using just a simplified constraint: every workstation `i` must have at least one resource `j` -> `sum(y[i, j] for j in j_idx) == 1` for all `i in i_idx`.
My objective is that every sold resource from the initial `y_line` brings us savings, every newly bought costs us and the solution (the new line) `y` has a processing cost for operating. I have defined the objective as follows:

```
y_delta = y - y_line  # delta between new line (y) and old line (y_line)
y_delta_plus = np.zeros(y.shape, dtype=object)  # 1
y_delta_minus = np.zeros(y.shape, dtype=object)  # 2

# I -> new bought resources
y_delta_plus[y_delta >= 0] = y_delta[y_delta >= 0]
# II -> sold resources
y_delta_minus[y_delta <= 0] = y_delta[y_delta <= 0]

c_i = y_delta_plus * EC  # invest
c_s = y_delta_minus * S  # savings
c_p = y * P  # processing cost
c_y = np.sum(c_s + c_i + c_p)
```

However, if I solve this model (full code see below), then the objective value (`5760`) doesn't match my sanity check calculations (`12430`). Would it be possible to set initial values for `y[i, j]`? Or is there another function to achieve this?

```py
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
import numpy as np


y_line = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1]])
S = np.array([[-260., -260., -260.],
              [-30.,  -30.,  -30.],
              [360.,  360.,  360.]], dtype=int)
EC = np.array([[1000, 1000, 1000],
               [2000, 2000, 2000],
               [5000, 5000, 5000]], dtype=int)
P = np.array([[720.,  720.,  720.],
              [1440., 1440., 1440.],
              [3600., 3600., 3600.]], dtype=int)

solver = pywraplp.Solver('stack', pywraplp.Solver.SAT_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

y = np.zeros_like(y_line, dtype=object)

i_idx = range(y_line.shape[0])
j_idx = range(y_line.shape[1])

for i in i_idx:
    for j in j_idx:
        y[i, j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'y[%i_%i]' % (i, j))

for i in i_idx:
    solver.Add(
        sum(y[i, j] for j in j_idx) == 1
    )


def objective(y, y_line):
    y_delta = y - y_line  # delta between new line (y) and old line (y_line)
    y_delta_plus = np.zeros(y.shape, dtype=object)  # 1
    y_delta_minus = np.zeros(y.shape, dtype=object)  # 2

    # I -> new bought resources
    y_delta_plus[y_delta >= 0] = y_delta[y_delta >= 0]
    # II -> sold resources
    y_delta_minus[y_delta <= 0] = y_delta[y_delta <= 0]

    c_i = y_delta_plus * EC  # invest
    c_s = y_delta_minus * S  # savings
    c_p = y * P  # processing
    return np.sum(c_s + c_i + c_p)

c_y = objective(y=y, y_line=y_line)
solver.Minimize(
    c_y
)

# [START solve]
print("Number of constraints:", solver.NumConstraints())
print("Number of variables:", solver.NumVariables())
status = solver.Solve()
# [END solve]

y_new = np.zeros_like(y)
for i in range(y_line.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y_line.shape[1]):
        if y[i, j].solution_value() > 0:
            y_new[i, j] = y[i, j].solution_value()

print(f"Objective sat: {solver.Objective().Value()}")
print(y_new)

# Number of constraints: 3
# Number of variables: 9
# Objective sat: 5760.0
# [[1.0 0 0]
#  [1.0 0 0]
#  [1.0 0 0]]

# %%
c_y_test = objective(y=y_new, y_line=y_line)
c_y_test # -> 12430.0
```

Comment: IntVars are not integers, so you have to make sure your numpy operations are doing what you want (eg: `y_delta <= 0` and `y_delta >= 0` return True for everything)

Comment: Thanks, I know, however I don't know another way to calculate this sort of relation...

Comment: CP-SAT usage is all about decomposition (based on the given primitives). Without a clear understanding about the internals of or-tools python-wrapper and numpy, i would be careful about numpy-heavy usage. It works to some extent, but there are some problematic places. That being said,  `y_delta_plus[y_delta >= 0] = y_delta[y_delta >= 0]` just looks like clipping towards nonnegative output-range. This is basically looped `AddMaxEquality(y_delta_plus[i], [y_delta[i], cp.NewConstant(0)])`. A general pattern: introduce helper/auxiliary-variables a-priori -> `y_delta_plus[i] = cp.NewIntVar(...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yet, I still couldn't exactly figure it out ... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model can be solved. However, not with the approach, I chose in the first place. Using a `pywraplp` model it didn't work, yet with a `cp_model` it can be solved using predefined variables (as mentioned by @sascha). The arrays `y_line`, `S`, `EC` and `P` are the same as above. The solemn constraint is the same as well. Yet, the "filtering" I could solve using:

```py
for i in range(len(y_cp.flatten())):
    model.AddElement(i, y_delta.flatten().tolist(), y_cp.flatten().tolist()[i] - y_line.flatten().tolist()[i])

for i in i_idx:
    for j in j_idx:
        model.AddMaxEquality(y_delta_plus[i, j], [y_delta[i, j], model.NewConstant(0)])
        model.AddMinEquality(y_delta_minus[i, j], [y_delta[i, j], model.NewConstant(0)])

model.Minimize(
    np.sum(y_delta_plus * EC) + np.sum(y_delta_minus * S) + np.sum(y_cp * P)
)
```

The solving and sanity check yields:

```py
solver_cp = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver_cp.Solve(model)

y_new_cp = np.zeros_like(y_cp)
for i in i_idx:
    for j in j_idx:
        if solver_cp.Value(y_cp[i, j]) > 0:
            y_new_cp[i, j] = solver_cp.Value(y_cp[i, j])

print(f"Objective cp: {solver_cp.ObjectiveValue()}")
print(y_new_cp)

# Objective cp: 5760.0
# [[1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0]
#  [1 0 0]]

c_y_test = objective(y=y_new_cp, y_line=y_line)
c_y_test # -> 5760 -> Correct
```

The `cp_model` could solve it and match the sanity check.
With the `pywraplp` model I couldn't figure out how to solve it.